# The size of the generated library significantly increased after referencing -llog in the C++ code

Tags: linker, android-ndk, c++17, shared-libraries, log4cxx

I compiled my C++ code into a dynamic library using the NDK. Initially, my code was linked with the log4 dynamic library and used -llog to include the Android logging library. However, later on, I removed the code references to log4 and only kept -llog. Surprisingly, the size of my dynamic library increased significantly compared to the previous build, and it introduced many symbols related to itanium_demangle. Why did this happen?

The -Os command did not have any effect, as observed when using the nm command, which revealed the presence of numerous itanium_demangle symbols. Analyzing the size with the size command showed a significant increase in debuginfo data.

**Update:**

Employed Russian is correct. I compared two approaches and obtained the following results:

```
liblog4cplus.so: shared definition of __cxa_demangle
/aarch64-linux-android/libc++abi.a: lazy definition of __cxa_demangle
/aarch64-linux-android/libc++abi.a(cxa_default_handlers.o): reference to __cxa_demangle
/aarch64-linux-android/libc++abi.a(cxa_demangle.o): definition of __cxa_demangle
```

From the above, it can be seen that when linking the log4 library, the functionality of `__cxa_demangle` is already included in the `log4` library, so it will not be included in the final generated library. However, when removing the `log4` linkage, the functionality of `__cxa_demangle` needs to be directly linked into the generated library, resulting in an increase in library size.

Answer (score 0):

> Why did this happen?

(Likely) because the symbols were previously provided by the `log4` shared library, but now remain unresolved and thus pulled in from `libc++.a` (or whatever C++ library you are using).

You can *see* where the symbol is referenced and where it is defined using `-Wl,-y,__cxa_demangle` on the link line. Use this command with the old and the new setup, and you should see the difference.

You should also read this [post](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking) to understand how linker works with archive libraries.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your thinking is correct. I compared two approaches and obtained the following results:

Comment: liblog4cplus.so: shared definition of __cxa_demangle


-----
/aarch64-linux-android/libc++abi.a: lazy definition of __cxa_demangle
/aarch64-linux-android/libc++abi.a(cxa_default_handlers.o): reference to __cxa_demangle
/aarch64-linux-android/libc++abi.a(cxa_demangle.o): definition of __cxa_demangle

Comment: From the above, it can be seen that when linking the log4 library, the functionality of __cxa_demangle is already included in the log4 library, so it will not be included in the final generated library. However, when removing the log4 linkage, the functionality of __cxa_demangle needs to be directly linked into the generated library, resulting in an increase in library size.

Comment: Later, I tried adding the linker option "c++_shared" so that __cxa_demangle is not included in the generated library, but is instead used through the dynamic library "libc++_shared.so". This way, the size of the library did not increase. However, this approach created another problem: I need to include "libc++_shared.so" in my project, which ultimately increased the size of the project significantly (my library was only 2.6MB, while "libc++_shared.so" is 6MB).

Comment: As for why my code requires the functionality of __cxa_demangle, I did not find any usage of it in my code through searching. Is there a way to remove __cxa_demangle from the library without using it? I look forward to your answer!

Comment: @YUEGU This is not a discussion site (and that's why comments are limited). Instead of providing many comments, just edit your question (as I have done). Also ask a separate question when you have one (you have _two_ separate questions) -- it's free.

Comment: @YUEGU When an answer helped you, upvote it. If the answer completely answered your question, accept it.